# Doesn't show route params in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am working on a marketing app. When I try to pass params to the product route, I can get these params on `console.log`. However, I cannot show the values of these params to the screen. What is the issue?

```js
export const ProductPage = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const { name, market, price } = route.params;

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        position: 'relative',
      }}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          marginTop: 10,
        }}>
        <Title
          style={{
            overflow: 'hidden',
            flex: 3,
          }}>
          {name}
        </Title>
        <View
          style={{
            overflow: 'hidden',
            flex: 1,
          }}>
          <Title>
            {price} {'\u20BA'}
          </Title>
          <Image
            source={MARKET_LOGOS[market]}
            style={{ borderRadius: 50, width: 50, height: 50 }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting params in console.log inside ProductPage, route.params has no problem check your style and check if your component shows anything